# How to add timestamp to a config (ini) file?

Tags: python, database, salesforce, config, ini

I have a config file that looks like this:

```
Username = username

Password = password

Security Token = security token

Timestamp = ???
```

I have a python script that initializes `'Timestamp'` but I need to add in the parameter for `'Timestamp'` such as `2020-07-01T00:00:00Z`. When I add that timestamp value in the config, the python script doesn't read the value and the python script pulls the data from all the days.

I already called the 'Timestamp' feature in the python script by doing:

```
Timestamp = file_dict['Timestamp']
```

and I thought the config (ini) file would read whatever value I placed, but it seems to ignore it. Is there any way to fix this? I am pulling data from salesforce.

Comment: What type is it for your Timestamp?

Comment: what do you mean what type? u mean what format should the timestamp be in? i wrote it in my post.

Comment: No, I mean is it an `int` or any other objects instantiated from `datetime` library? Or is it a `str`?

Comment: it's a timestamp

Comment: What do you see by `print(type(Timestamp))`

Comment: i dont have that in my script. do i need it somewhere? it can read the username, password etc fine